# Python subset Sum with floats?

Tags: python, sum, subset

I'm trying to see if a float can be constructed by adding values from a list of floats. Since the values are experimental, there is another array that contains error room values, such that the float can be constructed from the float list plus 0 or 1 of every value in the error room list, plus some additional error margin. The float may or may not be constructed from these parameters.

The length of lists, error margin and maximum size of the combination values are user defined.

I thought an efficient way to solve this problem was to have a function create and store every possible combination using the given parameters in an array, then check each float to see if it matches the combination, then print out the way the combination was obtained if a match exists.

for example, given a numlist [132.0423,162.0528,176.0321](3-10 values total)
and an errorlist [2.01454,18.0105546] (0-4 values total)
and an error room of 2, and a maximum combination size of 1000,

the float 153.0755519 can be constructed by 132.0423+2.01454+18.0105546 or numlist[0]+errorlist[0]+errorlist[1] and be within the error room

I have no idea how to go about solving such a problem. Perhaps using dynamic programming? I was thinking it would be computationally efficient to create the combinations array once via a separate function, then continuously pass it into a comparison function.

The background: the large floats are fragment masses that come from a mass spectrometer output and my team is attempting to analyze which fragments came from our initial protein that can only fragment into the pieces defined in numlist, but can occasionally lose a small functional group (water, alcohol, hydrogen etc.)